# How to add doctype in html page using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, doctype

I want to add a `doctype` for my particular page. How can I add it using JavaScript or jQuery?

I want to add `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">` using JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not sure if adding that dynamically will work. That would mean that the browser has to change layout modes dynamically, which means the page should be reloaded.

Comment: Cant you just add it at page load?

Comment: Yeah, adding a doctype with javascript (which I don't think possible anyway) would be totally pointless. The role of a doctype is to tell the browser how to interpret the page content. Adding it after the page is loaded is useless.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot add a DOCTYPE to the current document(or modify it).

From the [MDN-docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.doctype):
*doctype is a **read-only property**.*