# Altering IFrame src content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, iframe

I dont believe this can be done, but is it possible to alter the content of an iframe that is rendered via a src.

The 3rd party compiled ASP.Net control (Telerik RadEditor .Net 2 version) I use has an iframe in part of its rendered code and does not contain a doctype and it is causing problems in IE8 with certain elements.

As it is compiled, I can not add it in the source. I was wondering if it is possible to add it in another way?

I have tried multiple things in jquery such as:

```
$(element).html().prepend("doc type here");

$(element).html("doctype here" + $(element).html());
```

and all other kinds of dodgy work.

Comment: why are you not using custom content filter. You have the option to get/set radeditor value.

Comment: I tried looking at the custom content filter. But I did not understand how to inject a docType into it. It did not look like it achieves the task i am needing. Do you know how to?

Comment: i have posted the answer.check it.

Answer (score 1):

By `src`, you mean content, right? (`src` is an attribute of an iframe which specifies the URI of the iframe itself)

You may change the doctype by changing [the content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14289158/240613) of an iframe. One possible way is to recreate an iframe and reinsert the content, while prepending a doctype. Unfortunately, [it is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7159267/240613) to prepend a doctype to an existent iframe using DOM.

Example:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
var idocument = iframe.contentDocument;
idocument.open();
idocument.write("<!DOCTYPE html...") // Doctype goes here
idocument.write("<html>...</html>") // Content goes here
idocument.close();
```

Comment: Yeah thats what I mean, the url of the iframe has come from another page, so in my head my thought's are you cant change its content? I will try your example

Comment: @Nick: I apologize, Nick, I originally misread your question. I've edited my answer in order to focus on the doctype issue.

Comment: Thanks, this works to a degree, but it appears the 3rd party control is doing something funky with it. I'll just play with it a bit and let you know how it goes.

Comment: It is currently rendering like <iframe><html>doctype<body> etc. How can I get it to place the docType before the html tag?

Comment: How would this work for an existing iframe, instead of a new one?

Comment: @Nick: you have to create an iframe. Unfortunately, [it is not possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7159267/240613) to prepend a doctype to an existent iframe using DOM.

Comment: Oh Okay. That was the specific question I had asked at the start.

Answer (score 1):

I did domethin similar using iframes, using jQuery: `$('iframe').contents().find("#internaldiv")`, it works, but only if the iframe src and the main website are part of the same domain, in other cases you have to deal with the **same domain policy** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) and implement you cross domain policy in your server and in the other domain server.

Comment: Thanks, a previous answer identified how to do it, first, but thanks for mentioning the same domain policy. In this instance it was correct.